# automaticaly updating a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i im trying to check if more tasks are added to the board. So i can apply the drag system to all the new ones. The problem is that if i use a loop my variable falls out of the scope of my other function. I made it a global variable so i dont know why i can use it outside of the function. Maybe there is a way to check withoud using a whole seperate function. I added one test card and my dragging works on that one so its just the variable not updating.

```js
// ---------------------------
// Global variables
// ---------------------------

// Add button
const AddToDoButton = document.getElementById('new-to-do');

// Columns
const ToDoColumn = document.getElementById('to-do-column');
const InProgressColumn = document.getElementById('in-progress-column');
const CompleteColumn = document.getElementById('complete-column');

var Tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');

// ---------------------------
// Add new task structure
// ---------------------------

AddToDoButton.addEventListener('click', AddNewTask);

function AddNewTask(){
  // all HTML task parts
  const NewTaskContainer = document.createElement('div');
  const NewTaskHead = document.createElement('div');
  const NewTaskName = document.createElement('h3');
  const NewTaskDeleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  const NewTaskDescription = document.createElement('p');

  // adding drag
  NewTaskContainer.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');

  // adding all the classes
  NewTaskContainer.classList.add('task');
  NewTaskHead.classList.add('task-head');
  NewTaskDeleteButton.classList.add('delete-task');
  NewTaskDescription.classList.add('task-description');

  // adding all the content
  NewTaskName.innerHTML = "Task name";
  NewTaskDescription.innerHTML = "task description"
  NewTaskDeleteButton.innerHTML = "X"

  // HTML structure
  ToDoColumn.appendChild(NewTaskContainer);
  NewTaskContainer.appendChild(NewTaskHead);
  NewTaskHead.appendChild(NewTaskName);
  NewTaskHead.appendChild(NewTaskDeleteButton);
  NewTaskContainer.appendChild(NewTaskDescription);
}

// ---------------------------
// dragable functionality
// ---------------------------

// dragable tasks
function NewTasksCheck(){
  var Tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
  console.log(Tasks);
}

setInterval(NewTasksCheck, 1000);

Tasks.forEach(draggable => {
  draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    draggable.classList.add('dragging');
    console.log("dragstart");
  });

  draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
    draggable.classList.remove('dragging');
    console.log("dragend");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header > h1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

main {
  background-color: rgb(206, 234, 243);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.task-column {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  min-height: fit-content;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.task-column > * {
  margin: 10px;
}

.task {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: move;
}

.task-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.delete-task {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.add-to-do {
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: rgb(140, 233, 2);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.add-to-do:hover {
  transform: scale(110%);
}

.add-to-do:active {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.task.dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Planning</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <header>
    <h1>planning</h1>
    <button id="new-to-do" class="add-to-do">Add To Do</button>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div id="to-do-column" class="task-column">
      <h2>To Do</h2>

      <!-- example task -->
      <div draggable="true" class="task">
        <div class="task-head">
          <h3>ExampleTask</h3>
          <button class="delete-task">X</button>
        </div>
        <p class="task-description">
          This is an example
        </p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div id="in-progress-column" class="task-column">
      <h2>In Progress</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="complete-column" class="task-column">
      <h2>Complete</h2>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: If you're talking about `Tasks`, the `var` declaration in the function makes it a local variable. Just assign the variable without using `var` and you'll assign the global variable.

Comment: You could use `var Tasks = document.getElementByClassName("task");`. This is a "live NodeList", it's automatically updated when the DOM changes.

Comment: But you could also use an array, which you add to in the `AddNewTask()` function.

Comment: yes i am talking about the Tasks variable. Even if i remove the var and make it global it still doesnt trigger the console logs on the draggable.addEventlistener below.

Comment: You only added the event listeners to the initial contents of `Tasks`. When you add a new task, it won't have the event listeners.

Comment: That's something else you need to do in the `AddNewTask()` function.

Comment: i got it thanks I ran the newtaskscheck when the add button is pressed so it checks everytime a new one is added